# Library Bar Template

Tags: wpf, pixelsense

I want to edit the Template of a LibraryBar but i dont know how.
Can anyone of you tell me how to edit the Template of that Element.
Exactly I want to remove the border!

Answer (score 1):

Modifying the template is currently not possible: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/surfaceappdevelopment/thread/4da2f069-7c0e-4ccc-8cc5-b51b73f862ac

Maybe a SurfaceListbox is an alternative?